# Facebook oauth image

Tags: facebook

I have created a Facebook page tab app that requires authorisation. When the authorisation popup is displayed there is no image.

Here's a screen shot:

[image]

I've given the app a page tab image, so where does the oauth window get its image from? I can't find anywhere to upload it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook Application OAuth Images are specified on Facebook Developers site. [Direct link](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/)

1. choose your application from left sidebar
2. click Change Settings
3. Hover over the icon and choose Modify
4. Upload chosen pictures

Comment: which page do I upload the image on from that link?

Comment: So after that you need to choose your application from left sidebar.
After that click Change Settings -> Hover over the icon and choose Modify and from there